# How to query multiple things from a single element in cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to test the contents of a popup/modal in cypress. My first intuition was to just repeat the command to get the modal element like so:

```js
it('filter modal/popup', () => {
    cy.get('.some-button').click();
    cy.get('.some-modal').contains('abc').should('be.visible');
    cy.get('.some-modal').contains('def').should('be.visible');
    cy.getByCyTag('.some-modal').contains('xyz').should('be.visible');
});
```

However, "being a programmer", querying the 'folder-tree-filter-modal' three or even more times makes me a little uncomfortable. Since you can't store cypress objects in variables because they yield their results, I tried using cypress's then() promise based syntax, but that also doesn't really look much better:

```js
it('filter modal/popup', () => {
    cy.get('.some-button').click();
    cy.get('.some-modal').then((modal) => {
        cy.wrap(modal).should('be.visible');
        cy.wrap(modal).contains('abc').should('be.visible');
        cy.wrap(modal).contains('def').should('be.visible');
        cy.wrap(modal).contains('xyz').should('be.visible');
    });
});
```

Am I overthinking this or is there a better approach?

Comment: What does the `cy.getByCyTag` command translate into?

Comment: It just performs a get using a data-cy html attribute. I'll update it to be more generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`.within()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within#Syntax) command. All subsequent cy commands will query within an element.

```js
it('filter modal/popup', () => {
    cy.get('.some-button').click();
    cy.get('.some-modal').within( ()=> {
      cy.contains('abc').should('be.visible');
      cy.contains('def').should('be.visible');
      cy.contains('xyz').should('be.visible');
    });
});
```

Comment: this is probably even better than aliases :) thanks!

Comment: Using within() has the advantage of cleaner logs. When running Cypress UI via open, the log shows within() as nesting its function tests, reflecting the test code (and it does not repeat the containing gets for each test)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `cy.getByCyTag('file-tree-facette-search')` translates into something like `cy.get('file-tree-facette-search')`, then you use the `each` command for looping, something like:

```js
const values = ['abc', 'def', 'xyz']
cy.getByCyTag('file-tree-facette-search').each(($ele, index) => {
  cy.getByCyTag('folder-tree-filter-modal')
    .contains(values[index])
    .should('be.visible')
})
```

Or you can directly apply the traditional `forEach` if it works for your use case like this:

```js
const values = ['abc', 'def', 'xyz']
values.forEach((val) => {
  cy.getByCyTag('folder-tree-filter-modal').contains(val).should('be.visible')
})
```

Comment: I'd also like to be able to use other commands besides the .contains.should chain, but this seems nice, too for such usecases :)

Comment: Instead of contains you can use any other commands if you wish. This will work regardless.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think this syntax will work if need to call other commands between some of the others, like scrolling after the third one or something similar, will it?

Comment: You have to be more specific. What is the exact use-case you are looking for.

Comment: I posted my answer in a seperate answer post, but thanks anyway for yours. I didn't know there was an each function in cypress. That'll surely help me in the future :D

Answer (score 0):

I think what I was looking for was the ability to [add aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Sharing-Context) to cypress queries.

This allows be to do something like this:

```
cy.getByCyTag('folder-tree-filter-modal').as('modal');
    cy.get('@modal').should('be.visible');
    cy.get('@modal').contains('Darstellungsoptionen').should('be.visible');
    cy.get('@modal').contains('Nur Dateien mit Treffer anzeigen').should('be.visible');
    cy.get('@modal').contains('Genauigkeiten').should('be.visible');
    cy.get('#modal-facette-search .modal__inner').scrollTo('bottom');
    cy.get('@modal').contains('Dateitypen').should('be.visible');
    cy.get('#modal-facette-search .modal__inner').scrollTo('bottom');
    cy.get('@modal').get('.modal--active .modal__close').click();
    cy.get('@modal').should('not.be.visible');
```

Which is to just chain commands to the same object without having to retype the entire selector.